# C3 bar chart width is not working properly

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

hi I'm trying to build the bar chart using C3 js but I don't know for some reason the width is not getting set properly before it was working fine, I only made the color changes and it broke for some reason. Here is my code :

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
                size: {
                    height: 400,
                },
                data: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    json: [
                        { 'indicator': 'data1', 'Subject1': 100 },
                        { 'indicator': 'data2', 'Subject2': 90 },
                        { 'indicator': 'data3', 'Subject3': 66 },
                        { 'indicator': 'data4', 'Subject4': 50 },
                        { 'indicator': 'data5', 'Subject5': 50 },

                    ],
                    color: function (color, d) {
                        if (d.id && d.value) {
                            if (d.value<=40) {
                                return 'red';
                            }
                            else if (d.value<=70) {
                                return 'orange';
                            }
                            else {
                                return 'limegreen';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    keys: {
                        x: 'indicator',
                        value: ['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3','Subject4','Subject5']
                    }
                }, 
                legend:{hide:true},
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category',
                        tick: {
                            rotate: -55,
                            multiline: true

                        },
                        height: 190
                    },

                    y: {
                        show: false,
                        ticks: 3, // line added
                        padding: { top: 5, bottom: 0 },
                    }
                },
                bar: {
                    width: {
                        ratio: 0.5    
                    }
                },
                bindto: '#chart1'
            });
```

and the result I'm getting is, as you can see that in the image the width is not filled with the color of that bar.

[image: The result image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting 5 different data series (Subject 1-5) so it is reserving space at each value of 'indicator' (data 1-5) along the x-axis for 5 bars, but you are only setting a value for one series per data point in your data.

```
           { 'indicator': 'data1', 'Subject1': 100 },
           { 'indicator': 'data2', 'Subject2': 90 },
           { 'indicator': 'data3', 'Subject3': 66 },
           { 'indicator': 'data4', 'Subject4': 50 },
           { 'indicator': 'data5', 'Subject5': 50 },
```

I suspect Subject should be one series, so try this where there is only one data series Subject, and the bars then fit half the width at each 'indicator' value along the x-axis.

```
  { 'indicator': 'data1', 'Subject': 100 },
  { 'indicator': 'data2', 'Subject': 90 },
  { 'indicator': 'data3', 'Subject': 66 },
  { 'indicator': 'data4', 'Subject': 50 },
  { 'indicator': 'data5', 'Subject': 50 },


keys: {
   x: 'indicator',
   value: ['Subject']
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/68pgvsbh/5/

Your alternative if you do want to keep the different named Subject series for some reason is to add them as a stacked group

```
  groups: [["Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject3", "Subject4", "Subject5"]],
```